# Regrid a NetCDF file to match another without multiplication of pixels (CDO or R)

Tags: raster, r, netcdf

I have a NetCDF file (file1.nc) displaying rasterized information for a series of point locations. Each pixel with a number is surrounded by no data (see the colored pixels in the image below). I need to remap this file to match the grid of an additional NetCDF (file2.nc - see b/w pixels in the figure below) without changing the information contained (no interpolation of other math required) in file1.nc.

[image]

I tried to do that using CDO, using the `REMAP` function. In order to maintain the information intact, I selected the `-remapnn` command assigning to the nearest neighbor in file2.nc the value in file1.nc.

```
cdo -remapnn,file2.nc file1.nc output.nc
```

Unfortunately, this procedure splits the pixels in file1 when they equally cover pixels in file2 (see below).

[image]

How can I prevent this duplication of pixels? is there a method in `CDO` or `R` that could prevent this from happening?

Comment: Remapping changes pixel values, not alignment. You should be looking for something like "shift" though this will change  the position of all pixels by a uniform amount.

Comment: @Vince, thanks a lot for the suggestion, but please, note that the two grids have a different resolution: a simple shift cannot sole the issue (the layers are global, the image is just an example.)

Comment: Points are points, not pixels. you should convert them to a raster that aligns properly to avoid this issue.

Comment: it makes sense. The original dataset is provided in this format. I could convert it to a point shape preserving the information, then readjust the points to match the right pixels in the new grid (in case a point falls exactly between two pixels as it happens in the image) and then convert it again in a raster. I was just hoping for a faster way to do that...